# I can not use event in DevExpress structure.

Tags: c#, html, angular, devexpress

I'm using a drop-down-box. It's integrated with angular. It triggers an event I want to do. The attribute I'm using is onEnterKey. There is a method in the method. There is a method in the middle. I can not get any triggers, I use wrong or I have a different method. he is pushing me.

If you find a solution and teach it to use, I will be very happy.

```
 <dx-drop-down-box #exitCustomDropDownBox
                        [(value)]="exitCustomDropDownBoxValue"
                        valueExpr="id"
                        [displayExpr]="exitCustomGrid_displayExpr"
                        placeholder="Çıkış Gümrüğü"
                        [showClearButton]="true"
                        [(ngModel)]="requestModel.exitCustomId"
                        [dataSource]="exitCustomListResponse"
                        (ngModelChange)="setExitCustomName()"
                        (onEnterKey)="enterKey($event)">
        <dxo-drop-down-options [maxHeight]="200"></dxo-drop-down-options>
        <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
          <dx-data-grid [allowColumnReordering]="true" [dataSource]="exitCustomListResponse"
                        [selection]="{ mode: 'single' }"
                        [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
                        [paging]="{ enabled: true, pageSize: 10 }"
                        [filterRow]="{ visible: true }"
                        [scrolling]="{ mode: 'infinite' }"
                        [height]="265"

                        [(selectedRowKeys)]="exitCustomDropDownBoxGridSelectedRowKeys">
            <dxi-column dataField="code" caption="Kod"></dxi-column>
            <dxi-column dataField="name" caption="Ad"></dxi-column>

          </dx-data-grid>
        </div>
      </dx-drop-down-box>
```

this is the event that I want to do with TypeScript, the tabic is not that simple.

```
 enterKey(data) {
    debugger;
    this.isCustom = true;
    console.log(this.isCustom);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found such a qualification and it works if you have difficulty to investigate better and if you are experiencing the same problem this is the solution. If I stole your valuable time, I am sorry.

```
  <dx-drop-down-box #exitCustomDropDownBox
                        [(value)]="exitCustomDropDownBoxValue"
                        valueExpr="id"
                        [displayExpr]="exitCustomGrid_displayExpr"
                        placeholder="Çıkış Gümrüğü"
                        [showClearButton]="true"
                        [(ngModel)]="requestModel.exitCustomId"
                        [dataSource]="exitCustomListResponse"
                        (ngModelChange)="setExitCustomName()"
                        >
        <dxo-drop-down-options [maxHeight]="200"></dxo-drop-down-options>
        <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
          <dx-data-grid [allowColumnReordering]="true" [dataSource]="exitCustomListResponse"
                        [selection]="{ mode: 'single' }"
                        [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
                        [paging]="{ enabled: true, pageSize: 10 }"
                        [filterRow]="{ visible: true }"
                        [scrolling]="{ mode: 'infinite' }"
                        [height]="265"    
                        [(selectedRowKeys)]="exitCustomDropDownBoxGridSelectedRowKeys"
                        (onSelectionChanged)="enterKey($event)">
            <dxi-column dataField="code" caption="Kod"></dxi-column>
            <dxi-column dataField="name" caption="Ad"></dxi-column>

          </dx-data-grid>
        </div>
      </dx-drop-down-box>
```

The attribute I added is this = `(onSelectionChanged) = "enter Key ($ event)"`

I apologize again, if somebody took the time for this problem. :(